# PHP upload local file without button

Tags: php, html, file-upload, phpmyadmin

I am  trying to upload a file but i'm not using a upload button.
I want to upload a local file path for e.g `C://file` etc I currently  use

```
$_FILES['file']['name']
```

I would like to use for e.g `http://localhost/uploadfile_frompath?filepath=C://file.txt` As I would like to use the PHP call as a API to upload files

Is there a way to set the `$_Files` to a specif local file?

Comment: There is no way to upload a file from the client, without having the user actively select it first. It would _obviously_ be a massive security hole.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would have to FTP the file. The URL i would like to call is from a C# application

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that, resp. how it is supposed to relate to the question you initially asked.

Comment: You can try [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: @CBroe Apologies that was badly phrased. The plan is so send a file to a url i.e.e post the filename to an address and then in the php it uploads the file. Simulating the click upload button etc. The reason the c# was mentioned is we have an application that uses api's in php to interact and we wanted to add file upload functionality to it.

Comment: That would only work for files that are in the server’s file system to begin with. The PHP on _your_ server can not just go and download `C://file.txt` from _my_ machine.